# How to create dependencies to system libraries with Buck2 for Python

Tags: python, buck2

This is my second attempt trying to work with Buck2. It looks very promising but lacks proper documentation and examples.

I want to have python_binary or python_library rules with a dependency to numpy or any other python libraries.
Those libraries are installed on the system using pip install or other means.
How do I make a dependency to those libraries that are already installed on the system?